# Sync SQL Server indices

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

We're facing a database with a lot of duplicate tables (temp and productive) which have the same columns, but somehow weren't given the same indices.

During the day the temp tables are filled with current data and swapped with the productive tables. So every other hour the queries won't find the indices and are therefore running slower.

Is there a way to sync the indices of two SQL Server tables?

Regards

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing built-in to do that. Only you can decide how to resolve discrepancies; a tool can't do that automatically. You'll need to use a schema comparison tool. SQL Compare works well.